# GetRange of a value (the value indicates a cell address)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have in 'Back'!AC3 a formula that returns a cell address (the formula is "A"&**V2**&":T"&**V2** that returns 'A44:T44' (**V2** can change)

I want to use this address in a macro :

```
function border() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Facture');
  const back = doc.getSheetByName('Back');
  var address = back.getRange('AC3').getValue();
  spreadsheet.sheet.getRange('address').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(null, true, true, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
```

It doesn't work... Can someone help me to fix it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building the range reference text string using concatenation, like this:

```
function border() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rangeA1 = 'Facture!' + ss.getRange('Back!AC3').getValue();
  ss.getRange(rangeA1)
    .setBorder(false, true, true, true, false, false, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
}
```

Comment: I have another question, do you know I how can run the macro 'border' every time  the value of the cell 'back!AC3' changes (the value changes automatically) ?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Answer (score 0):

```
function border() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().forEach(r => r.setBorder(false, true, true, true, false, false, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the code of doubleunary works very well, so I think I will use it. But I have another question, do you know I how can run the macro 'border' every time  the value of the cell 'back!AC3' changes (the value changes automatically)

Comment: There is no trigger generated for changes caused by other scripts or formulas

Comment: This solution works for non overlapping selected ranges.  ie ranges created by holding down the control key

Comment: I understand... The cell 'Back!AC3' changes automatically when the user select a value in a dropdown list which is in 'A remplir!F2'. Is that possible to trigger the macro when the user select a value in 'A remplir!F2' ?

Comment: I think so as long as it's a user edit.